# Add or append new column to csv file using shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, awk

I have a CSV file it includes some columns, in that I have the start time and end time. My requirement is to get the difference between the time and add the difference to a new column.

I'm getting the difference between time but not able to add it into new column properly for each line.

This is my sample csv.

> 4,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:56:40Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1
>   3,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:54:25Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1
>   2,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:52:59Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1
>   1,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:46:52Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1

This is the script.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cat a.csv | while read line
       do
              created_at=$(date -d $(echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $3}') +%s)
              merged_at=$(date -d $(echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $6}') +%s)
              echo $created_at $merged_at
              diff=$(( $merged_at - $created_at ))
              h=`expr $diff / 3600`
              m=`expr $diff  % 3600 / 60`
              s=`expr $diff % 60`
              diff=$(printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $h $m $s)
              echo $diff
              awk -v v1="$diff" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$9=v1; print}' a.csv >> b.csv
done
```

I'm getting the output something like this.

```
4,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:56:40Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1,00:00:22
3,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:54:25Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1,00:00:22
2,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:52:59Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1,00:00:22
1,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:46:52Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1,00:00:22
4,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:56:40Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1,00:00:30
3,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:54:25Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1,00:00:30
2,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:52:59Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1,00:00:30
1,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:46:52Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1,00:00:30
4,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:56:40Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1,00:02:20
3,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:54:25Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1,00:02:20
2,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:52:59Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1,00:02:20
1,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:46:52Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1,00:02:20
4,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:56:40Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1,00:00:33
3,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:54:25Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1,00:00:33
2,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:52:59Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1,00:00:33
1,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:46:52Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1,00:00:33
```

Which is append the difference to all the line.

But my requirement to get the difference of time only for that line.
The output should be like this.

```
4,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:56:40Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:57:02Z,1,1,00:00:22
3,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:54:25Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:54:55Z,1,1,00:00:30
2,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:52:59Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:55:19Z,1,1,00:02:20
1,ganesh-28,2019-09-26T16:46:52Z,closed,harshavardhanc,2019-09-26T16:47:25Z,1,1,00:00:33
```

Please someone help me to achieve this.

Comment: Your last line re-reads / appends the whole file (`... a.csv >> b.csv`) at every loop iteration - presumably what you intended is something like `... <<<"$line" >> b.csv`

Comment: Gosh, just like that @steeldriver. I have been on this knowing that passing a file will make awk repeat the same loop sequence but unable to realize that I can pass a line to that command! No wonder your the steeldriver

Answer (score 1):

The last awk command inside your loop

```
awk -v v1="$diff" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$9=v1; print}' a.csv >> b.csv
```

processes the whole file `a.csv` at every loop iteration, and appends the whole result to `b.csv` each time.

Presumably what you intended was to apply the command only to the current contents of the `$line` variable - in `bash` you can do that with a *here string*

```
awk -v v1="$diff" -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$9=v1; print}' <<<"$line" >> b.csv
```

---

However, processing CSV files line-by-line in a shell loop is not generally recommended - you might want to consider using a utility that provides datetime processing natively (Perl, Python, GNU Awk) or [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) ex.

```
mlr --csvlite --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output put -S '
  $9 = strftime(strptime($6,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") - strptime($3,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),"%T")
' a.csv > b.csv
```

(remove `--implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output` if your CSV file does actually have headers).

See also

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. But actually I had re-written my script to achieve this in a different way.